# avoid reflection api to invoke dynamic methods

Tags: java, performance, reflection

Please help me how to invoke java method dynamically without using reflection api  I am writing all java function name in xls file.  My xlsreader reads that function name one by one and invokes it reflection api but i want to avoid reflection api...please help me

Comment: A few things come to mind, like using a factory pattern. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Full dynamic invocation can only be done via reflection. However, you can use the following general approach:

1. generate the invocation code according to your use case (i.e., load the xls file and generate a .java file). Have it implement an interface for all your dynamically generated classes which defines an execute() method.
2. Compile the generated file using the built-in compiler API (`ToolSupport.getSystemJavaProvider`)
3. Load the newly compiled class with a custom `ClassLoader`
4. Instantiate the class and call execute() on it.